Issues while displaying tabs - tab link doesnt work working under Nuxt Ionic
I have layouts, as default.vue in layouts folder and then pages in the pages directory with a bookings folder which has further create.vue, index.vue and a settings folder which has account.vue and profile.vue. If I try to link these tabs with the help of $route.push, it routes very well, but the rest of my links stop working for that specific page.
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <nuxt />
 <ion-tabs>
   
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
          <ion-icon :icon="home" />
          <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
          <nuxt-link to="/home" />
        </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
        <ion-icon :icon="car" />
        <ion-label>Rides</ion-label>
        <nuxt-link to="/rides" />
      </ion-tab-button>
      
      <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
          <ion-icon :icon="helpCircle" />
          <ion-label>Help</ion-label>
          <nuxt-link to="/help" />
        </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="tab4" @click="$router.push('/bookings')">
        <ion-icon :icon="helpCircle" />
        <ion-label>Help</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="tab5">
        <ion-icon :icon="person" />
        <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
        <nuxt-link to="/settings" />
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script>
     import { home, helpCircle, library, car, person} from 'ionicons/icons';
     export default {
     name: 'DefaultLayout',
      auth: false,
      data() {
        return {
           helpCircle,
         library,
          car,
         home,
         person
       };
    },
  methods: 
  {
  }
}
</script>

I have followed the app tabs listed under Nuxt IONIC and made some changes. First, I kept tabs data in tabs page under pages directory. So this is my tabs.vue:
<template>
    <ion-page>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-tabs>
          <ion-router-outlet />
          
          <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
            <ion-tab-button tab="tab1" href="/tabs/tab1">
              <ion-icon :icon="home" />
              <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button tab="tab2" href="/tabs/tab2">
              <ion-icon :icon="car" />
              <ion-label>Photos</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button tab="tab3" href="/tabs/tab3">
              <ion-icon :icon="helpCircle" />
              <ion-label>Tab 3</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button tab="tab4" href="/tabs/tab4">
              <ion-icon :icon="person" />
              <ion-label>Animation</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
          </ion-tab-bar>
        </ion-tabs>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
  </template>
  <script>
  import { home, helpCircle, library, car, person} from 'ionicons/icons';
  export default {
  name: 'Tabs Page',
    auth: false,
    data() {
      return {
        helpCircle,
      library,
      car,
      home,
      person
      };
    },
    methods: 
    {
    },
  }
  </script> 

Now the tabs folder has three folders: tabs1, tabs2, tabs3. Each folder has an index.vue. Example of tabs1.vue:
<template>
    <ion-page>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Tab 2</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        Tab 2 content
      </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
  </template>
 <script>
 export default {
 name: 'Tab 2 Page',
   auth: false,
   data() {
     return {
      
     };
   },
   methods: 
   {
   }
 }


    </script>

This shows  tab with id: "undefined" does not exist. If I add routes in my export default script below this: tabs.vue
  router: {
        extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
        routes.push(
            {
            name: 'tab1',
            path: '/tabs/tab1',
            component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/tabs/tab1.vue')
            },
            {
            name: 'tab2',
            path: '/tabs/tab2',
            component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/tabs/tab2.vue')
            },
            // Add routes for other tabs similarly
        )
        }
    }

It returns ._router.init is not a function otherwise on click of tab. However, my console shows that the tab with id: "undefined" does not exist.
For General Routing, I use an axios call for calling my APIs. In the front end, I work with
<nuxt-link to="/settings"> and @click="$router.push('/bookings/create')" 

I tried also tried this, which worked,
@click="$router.push('/bookings/create')" 

What is the correct way of doing this? These tabs should display for all pages in the bottom section. So, if I move this to layouts and apply layouts as default in each page script, it gives routing issues.
